# Production of DEM on ArcMap from LiDAR data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, lidar, hydrology

I am trying to produce a DEM for my dissertation (i'm relatively new to ArcGIS) so that I can conduct hydrological analyses of catchments. I have downloaded LIDAR (.laz 2x2 km) data and have created a las dataset. It is my understanding that I now need to make this into a terrain dataset to analyse the data. I have made a feature dataset and have imported LIDAR ground points into a multipoint feature class. However, I do not know what to do next. I have read that adding breaklines is important and that there is more preprocessing I need to do.I have catchments that are separate to each other so I believe I may need to merge them. I am looking for help as to what processes I need to execute to have a data set upon which I can use the hydrology toolbox to carry out accurate analysis.

Comment: Have you seen this page "Creating raster DEMs and DSMs from large lidar point collections", http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/las-dataset/lidar-solutions-creating-raster-dems-and-dsms-from-large-lidar-point-collections.htm

Comment: Yes I have. I was just looking for a quick guide as to the processes I need to carry out to get something I can use. I.e you need to... create a raster layer --> add breaklines which are in such and such format and are generated by --> merge/stitch data together using toolbox ... --> ... --> ... --> to arrive at a usable model...